# Displaying user phone on my account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-accounts, user-data

I Would like in my WooCommerce web shop to show registered user phone, but dont know how to do that. I Read all themes that i found on StackOverflow for that, but none of suggested solutions, dont resolved my issue.

I have tried inserting this:

```
'billing_phone' => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_phone', true ),
```

inserting into

```
/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-address.php
```

But still user phone not shown in **`my-account`** page.

Can someone give me some tips, how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the customer phone you need the correct **`meta_key`** is **`'billing_phone'`** in **`wp_usermeta`** table, so your code will be:

```
$customer_phone = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true );

// Displaying customer phone:
echo '<br>'; # Going on line below
echo __('Phone: ', 'woocommerce') . $customer_phone;
```

This surely will work

Comment: Here: http://i.imgur.com/P9yBPIt.jpg?1

This is code from that page: `https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/myaccount/my-address.php`